# Mail id in webpage not shown correctly in webview

Tags: android, webview

My app supports arabic language. I load a webpage in the web view using an url. The web page is both in Englis and Arabic language. The web page contains a mail id like 'info@xxx.com' in English in both English and Arabic language web page content. When Arabic language web page content is loaded in the webview, the mail id does not get display correctly. It displays some garabage value. How to resolve it?

Comment: i think you have to use enableJavascript on webview

Comment: I have enabled the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set **mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)** for the webview settings.

Comment: I have enabled it.

Comment: I'm also found same bug. Worked on all Nexus devices but all Samsung devices lost my user changes. I know the below method is deprecated but it solved my issue.   webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}